# Can only set style.marginLeft once?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have navigation menu that hides to the right of the screen, I can hide it by setting style.marginLeft, but when I try to set it a second time (to unhide) nothing happens.

```js
function navroll(state) {
  if(state == true) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.marginLeft = window.innerWidth + 5 +"px";
    document.getElementById("btn-unhide").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.marginLeft = window.innerWidth - document.getElementById("navbar").offsetWidth - 5 + "px";
    //document.getElementById("btn-unhide").style.display = "none";
  }
}
function keepscale() {
  if(document.getElementById("btn-unhide").style.display == "block") {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.marginLeft = window.innerWidth - document.getElementById("navbar").offsetWidth - 5 + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
#btn-unhide {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  left: 90%;
  transition: 3s;
}
#navbar .inner {
  position: absolute;
}
#navbar {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: fixed;
  left: 60%;
}
#navbar {
  transition: margin-left 3s;
}
.nav-button {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #f25646;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  float: right;
  border-block-start-color: black;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  outline: none;
}
.nav-button:hover {
  background-color: #a7382c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Revista CNAIC</title>
    <link href="css/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body onresize="keepscale()">
    <div id="navwrapper">
      <div id="btn-unhide">
          <button onclick="navroll(false)"> unhide </button>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar">
        <div class="btn-sign">
        <button class="nav-button">Proiecte si Activitati Extrascolare
        </button>
        <button class="nav-button">Rezultate Academice
        </button>
        <button class="nav-button">Interviul Saptamanii
        </button>
        </div>
        <div id="btn-hide">
          <button onclick="navroll(true)"> hide </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="js/navbar.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried many formulas to get it to unhide like style.transform = " translate(-" window.innerWidth - *myelement*.offsetWidth - 5 + "px);"
I don't know what to try anymore.

Comment: `window.innerWidth - document.getElementById("navbar") - 5 + "px"` will return an invalid property value so that could be the issue here.  What styles does the element in question end up with after the second time?  If you could show what it looks like in dev tools that would help us troubleshoot

Comment: Sorry I meant document.getElementById("navbar").offsetWidth

Comment: When u try to unhide, your calculated margin is wrong. Set the marginLeft to 0 instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just reset the margin left to `0` for unhide

```js
function navroll(state) {
  if(state == true) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.marginLeft = window.innerWidth + 5 +"px";
    document.getElementById("btn-unhide").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.marginLeft = "0px";
    //document.getElementById("btn-unhide").style.display = "none";
  }
}
function keepscale() {
  if(document.getElementById("btn-unhide").style.display == "block") {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.marginLeft = window.innerWidth - document.getElementById("navbar").offsetWidth - 5 + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
#btn-unhide {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  left: 90%;
  transition: 3s;
}
#navbar .inner {
  position: absolute;
}
#navbar {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: fixed;
  left: 60%;
}
#navbar {
  transition: margin-left 3s;
}
.nav-button {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #f25646;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  float: right;
  border-block-start-color: black;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  outline: none;
}
.nav-button:hover {
  background-color: #a7382c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Revista CNAIC</title>
    <link href="css/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body onresize="keepscale()">
    <div id="navwrapper">
      <div id="btn-unhide">
          <button onclick="navroll(false)"> unhide </button>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar">
        <div class="btn-sign">
        <button class="nav-button">Proiecte si Activitati Extrascolare
        </button>
        <button class="nav-button">Rezultate Academice
        </button>
        <button class="nav-button">Interviul Saptamanii
        </button>
        </div>
        <div id="btn-hide">
          <button onclick="navroll(true)"> hide </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="js/navbar.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```